# AngularJS e2e Testing: How To Get value of repeater().count()?

Tags: angularjs, karma-runner, end-to-end

## Problem

Calling `repeater('#myTable tr','Rows').count();` returns a `Future`, not an integer.  I need to get the integer value so I can confirm that an additional row was added to a table.

## Code

```
it('should add a new user when save button is clicked',function()
    {
        showModal();

        //here I'm trynig to store the row count of my table into  a local variable.
        //a future is returned who's 'value' field is undefined.
        var memberCount = repeater('#memberTable tr','Member Rows').count();

        //this outputs 'undefined'
        console.log(memberCount.value);


        input('editedMember.name').enter('John');
        input('editedMember.grade').enter(5);
        input('editedMember.ladderPosition').enter(3);

        element('#saveMemberButton').click();
        sleep(1);
        expect(element(modalId).css('display')).toBe('none');

        //here is where I want to do the comparison against the above stored memberCount
        expect(repeater('#memberTable tr', 'Member Rows').count()).toBe(memberCount.value + 1);


    });
```

## Test Result

```
Chrome 25.0 e2e should add a new user when save button is clicked FAILED
    expect repeater 'Member Rows ( #memberTable tr )' count toBe null
    /Users/jgordon/learning/chessClub/web-app/test/e2e/scenarios.js:45:3: expected null but was 6
Chrome 25.0: Executed 2 of 2 (1 FAILED) (1 min 4.117 secs / 1 min 3.773 secs)
```

Answer (score 4):

Drilling into the source code for Angularjs' e2e support reveals that you have to call `execute()` on the `Future` to have it populate its value.  Also, when you call `execute` you have to provide a "done" function to the `execute()` otherwise Testacular will (oddly enough!) skip your test.

## Code

```
var rowCountFuture = repeater('#memberTable tr','Member Rows').count();
        
        rowCountFuture.execute(function(){
        });
        
        var memberCount = rowCountFuture.value;
```

While I'm jazzed to see this works, I'm concerned there may be some asynchronous bugs that could come out of this, also, I feel like this is a hack and not the right way to do it.  Any ideas?

Comment: I've just bumped into this problem as well, could you please elaborate more regarding your solution ? if can provide code example it'll be very helpful !

Thanks !

Comment: Call the `count()` method like the 1st line above.  That returns a `Future` -- an object that will fetch the count of your repeater when you call the `execute()` method.  Pass in an empty function to satisfy it.  After `execute()` has been called, you can get the count of your rows by accessing the `Future`'s `value` property.

Comment: I've tried it already, but then I'm getting next error : "Frame window is not accessible."

Comment: I've revisited this and find I'm getting the same error, too.  I wonder if there was some update that changed this behaviour.  I'm marking this as unanswered.

Comment: Brilliance. This is the kind of thing that makes Angular very difficult to pick up, but very exciting and powerful at the same time.

Answer (score 2):

Based on the latest Protractor version:

```
it('should add a new user when save button is clicked', function() {
    var memberCount;
    element.all(by.repeater('#memberTable tr','Member Rows')).count().then(function(value) {
        memberCount = value;
    });
    ...
    // then do all your entering user info, saving etc.
    ...
    browser.refresh(); // or however you want to load new data
    expect(element.all(by.repeater('#memberTable tr','Member Rows')).count()).toEqual(memberCount + 1);
});
```

Answer (score 1):

I've run into the same issue, and have seen confusing results when testing `value` returned *after* calling `execute()`. I've found this method works more reliably:

```
var getCount = repeater('ul li').count();
getCount.execute(function(value) {
    expect(value).toEqual(3);
});
```

Comment: Thanks, David.  I'll check it out.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this most easily in the async promise returned by the locator

```
element.all(By.repeater 'thing in things').then(function(elements){
      count = elements.length;
      expect(count).toEqual(3);
});
```